# How do I boot from CD in GNU grub?

Tags: boot, grub2

Forgot my Admin password to Windows and have oph crack on a CD but how do I boot from CD in GNU grub?

Comment: Normally, you tell the computer BIOS to boot from CD rather than the fixed disk.  Sometimes there's even a key to press at startup to bring up a menu.  But if that's not possible, there might be a way using GRUB; interesting question, but unfortunately I've never seen anything other than hard disk designators in grub.

Comment: When you say "Admin password" do you mean a BIOS boot pw, or a password only on Windows>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to boot from CD is to change the boot order in the BIOS. Often pressing the F12 key during POST (PowerOnSelfTest) will temporarily do this, otherwise you can 'permanently' change it in setup (F2 or DEL usually).

If your `grub.cfg` file doesn't already have the commands to boot from CD, typing them manually would be tedious.

Comment: Worked, thanks you're a scholar and a gentlemen.